# Centered CSS Menu (I've reviewed many answers but can't figure this one out)

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

I am sorry in advance, I know multiple postings on this topic is a drag.. But I have tried at least 10 different solutions and cannot figure out why this menu will not center.

Here is the menu as a live screen shot that I would like centered:

[image]

Here is the life page if you want to see the full source:
https://www.orangeinsurance.com/contractors-NEW.html

Thanks in advance. 
CSS

```
#menu, #menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 2px auto;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    background-color: #111;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111); 
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#444), to(#111));    
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);  
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777, 0 1px 0 #666 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777, 0 1px 0 #666 inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777, 0 1px 0 #666 inset;
}

#menu:before,
#menu:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

#menu:after {
    clear: both;
}

#menu {
    zoom:1;
}

#menu li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #222;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #444;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #444;
    position: relative;
}

#menu a {
    float: left;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}

#menu li:hover > a {
    color: #fafafa;
}

*html #menu li a:hover { /* IE6 only */
    color: #fafafa;
}

#menu ul {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    _margin: 0; /*IE6 only*/
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;    
    background: #444;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#444), to(#111));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111); 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
    background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);  
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;  
}

#menu li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    margin: 0;
}

#menu li:last-child
{
border-right: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
}

#menu ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 150px;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    _margin: 0; /*IE6 only*/
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);  
}

#menu ul li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    _line-height: 0; /*IE6 only*/
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111, 0 2px 0 #666;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111, 0 2px 0 #666;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111, 0 2px 0 #666;
}

#menu ul li:last-child {   
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;    
}

#menu ul a {    
    padding: 10px;
    width: 130px;
    _height: 10px; /*IE6 only*/
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: none;
    text-transform: none;
}

#menu ul a:hover {
    background-color: #0186ba;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#67c6dd,  #0186ba);  
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#67c6dd), to(#0186ba));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#67c6dd, #0186ba);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#67c6dd, #0186ba);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#67c6dd, #0186ba);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#67c6dd, #0186ba);
}

#menu ul li:first-child > a {
    -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

#menu ul li:first-child > a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: -6px;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #444;
}

#menu ul ul li:first-child a:after {
    left: -6px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    border-left: 0; 
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid #3b3b3b;
}

#menu ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
    border-bottom-color: #67c6dd; 
}

#menu ul ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
    border-right-color: #0299d3; 
    border-bottom-color: transparent;   
}

#menu ul li:last-child > a {
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}

/* Mobile */
#menu-trigger {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    /* nav-wrap */
    #menu-wrap {
        position: relative;
    }

    #menu-wrap * {
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    /* menu icon */
    #menu-trigger {
        display: block; /* show menu icon */
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        cursor: pointer;        
        padding: 0 0 0 35px;
        border: 1px solid #222;
        color: #fafafa;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #111;
        background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat 10px center, -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111); 
        background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat 10px center, -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111); 
        background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat 10px center, -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
        background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat 10px center, -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
        background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABIAAAAPCAMAAADeWG8gAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAyBpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9iZS54bXAAAAAAADw/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdpbj0i77u/IiBpZD0iVzVNME1wQ2VoaUh6cmVTek5UY3prYzlkIj8+IDx4OnhtcG1ldGEgeG1sbnM6eD0iYWRvYmU6bnM6bWV0YS8iIHg6eG1wdGs9IkFkb2JlIFhNUCBDb3JlIDUuMC1jMDYwIDYxLjEzNDc3NywgMjAxMC8wMi8xMi0xNzozMjowMCAgICAgICAgIj4gPHJkZjpSREYgeG1sbnM6cmRmPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5LzAyLzIyLXJkZi1zeW50YXgtbnMjIj4gPHJkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiByZGY6YWJvdXQ9IiIgeG1sbnM6eG1wPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvIiB4bWxuczp4bXBNTT0iaHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wL21tLyIgeG1sbnM6c3RSZWY9Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC9zVHlwZS9SZXNvdXJjZVJlZiMiIHhtcDpDcmVhdG9yVG9vbD0iQWRvYmUgUGhvdG9zaG9wIENTNSBXaW5kb3dzIiB4bXBNTTpJbnN0YW5jZUlEPSJ4bXAuaWlkOjE2QjAxNjRDOUNEOTExRTE4RTNFRkI1RDQ2MUYxOTQ3IiB4bXBNTTpEb2N1bWVudElEPSJ4bXAuZGlkOjE2QjAxNjREOUNEOTExRTE4RTNFRkI1RDQ2MUYxOTQ3Ij4gPHhtcE1NOkRlcml2ZWRGcm9tIHN0UmVmOmluc3RhbmNlSUQ9InhtcC5paWQ6MTZCMDE2NEE5Q0Q5MTFFMThFM0VGQjVENDYxRjE5NDciIHN0UmVmOmRvY3VtZW50SUQ9InhtcC5kaWQ6MTZCMDE2NEI5Q0Q5MTFFMThFM0VGQjVENDYxRjE5NDciLz4gPC9yZGY6RGVzY3JpcHRpb24+IDwvcmRmOlJERj4gPC94OnhtcG1ldGE+IDw/eHBhY2tldCBlbmQ9InIiPz42AEtnAAAABlBMVEX///////9VfPVsAAAAAnRSTlP/AOW3MEoAAAAWSURBVHjaYmAgFzBiACKFho6NAAEGAD07AG1pn932AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) no-repeat 10px center, linear-gradient(#444, #111);
        -moz-border-radius: 6px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777, 0 1px 0 #666 inset;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777, 0 1px 0 #666 inset;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777, 0 1px 0 #666 inset;
    }

    /* main nav */
    #menu {
        margin: 0; padding: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 40px;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: #444;
        display: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;   
    }

    #menu:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 25px;
        top: -8px;
        border-left: 8px solid transparent;
        border-right: 8px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 8px solid #444;
    }   

    #menu ul {
        position: static;
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        margin: 0;
        background: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;           
    }

    #menu ul ul {
        margin: 0 0 0 20px !important;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;       
    }

    #menu li {
        position: static;
        display: block;
        float: none;
        border: 0;
        margin: 5px;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;           
    }

    #menu ul li{
        margin-left: 20px;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;       
    }

    #menu a{
        display: block;
        float: none;
        padding: 0;
        color: #999;
    }

    #menu a:hover{
        color: #fafafa;
    }   

    #menu ul a{
        padding: 0;
        width: auto;        
    }

    #menu ul a:hover{
        background: none;   
    }

    #menu ul li:first-child a:after,
    #menu ul ul li:first-child a:after {
        border: 0;
    }       

}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    #menu {
        display: block !important;
    }
}   

/* iPad */
.no-transition {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -ms-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    transition: none;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    display: none;          
}

#menu li:hover > .no-transition {
    display: block;
}
body,td,th {
font-family: Calibri;
color: #333;
    }
```

Comment: Please do not link to external sites, rather, include your relevant CSS and HTML markup here in your post. If you need to show a working example in addition to posting your code, create a fiddle at http://www.jsfiddle.net and link to that.

Comment: These look pretty much the same ... what's the specific problem?

Comment: It looks centered to me.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using floats on your `li` elements, use `display:inline-block;` You'll have to either increase the overall size of your `ul` or reduce the padding/margins of your `li` elements since they have a total width of more than 50% of the page...

Change this:

```
#menu li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #222;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #444;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #444;
    position: relative;
}
```

To this:

```
#menu li {
    border-right: 1px solid #222;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #444;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #444;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If you create a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) I can show you a working example...

Answer (score 0):

```
#menu li {
/* float: left;  --> Delete this*/
display: inline-block; /*use this */
}
```